# How to prevent pushing dynamic rows with duplicate values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am pushing dynamic row on click of add new button.

I wanted to display validation to stop pushing row if previous row has same value.

**For ex -** i have 5 fields namely productType, process Technology,subfamilyId,Package Lines
and batchSize.On click of add button i m pushing new empty rows,But i want to apply one validation on Add New button click.

Validation will check below condition

Suppose if i select below values in Row 1
productType - Red
processTechnology - Red
subfamilyId - Red
PackageLines - Red
batchSize - 2.5

And Again i select below values in Row 2,

productType - Red
processTechnology - Red
subfamilyId - Red
PackageLines - Red
batchSize - 2.5

But In above case, Row2 value is similar to Row 1, Then it will throw error on Add new button click.

**On every Add New Button click, New object will be added in below array**

```
this.items.value = [
    {productType: 'Laundry', processTechType: 'Continuous', subfamilyId: Array(1), lineId: Array(1), batchSize: 'NA'}
 {productType: 'Water Purification', processTechType: 'Batch', subfamilyId: Array(1), lineId: Array(1), batchSize: '34'}
];
```

Can anyone help me to do this logic, Below is my code

**Component code**

```
makeLineForm: FormGroup;  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.makeLineForm = this.fb.group({
      clusterId: ['', Validators.required],
      makeLineProcessList: this.fb.array([this.createItem(null)]),
    });
  }
  createItem(data) {
    const formgrp = this.fb.group({
      productType: ['', Validators.required],
      processTechType: ['', Validators.required],
      subfamilyId: ['', Validators.required],
      lineId: ['', Validators.required],
      batchSize: ['']
    });
    if (data) {
      formgrp.patchValue(data);
    }
    return formgrp;
  }
  addItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }
  get items() {
    return this.makeLineForm.get('makeLineProcessList') as FormArray;
  }
  addNewType() {    
    this.addItem(this.createItem(null));
  }


<div class="master-data-main-wrapper">
  
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <form [formGroup]="makeLineForm">        
            <div class="row">                
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <mat-label>Vendor</mat-label>
                    <input matInput class="mkline-input"
                        [class.inValidClass]="makeLineForm?.controls?.makeVendor?.invalid" placeholder="Vendor"
                        formControlName="makeVendor">
                </div>
            </div>

            <form [formGroup]="items" class="items">
                <div class="row dl-body" *ngFor="let subitem of items.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 pl-4">
                        <mat-label>Product Type</mat-label>
                        <mat-select class="mkline-input" formControlName="productType"
                            [class.inValidClass]="subitem?.controls?.productType?.invalid">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let prod of productTypes" [value]="prod.category">
                                {{prod.category}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                        <mat-label>Process Technology</mat-label>
                        <mat-select (selectionChange)="validateBatchSize($event,i)" class="mkline-input"
                            formControlName="processTechType"
                            [class.inValidClass]="subitem?.controls?.processTechType?.invalid">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type"> {{type}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                        <mat-label>Sub-Family Make</mat-label>
                        <mat-select class="mkline-input" formControlName="subfamilyId"
                            [class.inValidClass]="subitem?.controls?.subfamilyId?.invalid" multiple>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let subfamily of subfamlies | async" [value]="subfamily"> {{subfamily}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                        <mat-label>Package Lines</mat-label>
                        <mat-select class="mkline-input" formControlName="lineId"
                            [class.inValidClass]="subitem?.controls?.lineId?.invalid" multiple>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let line of lines | async" [value]="line.lineId"> {{line.name}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                        <mat-label>Batch Size (Ton)</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" (keypress)="validateBatchSizeForDecimal($event)"
                            [readonly]="batchReadOnly" [class.inValidClass]="subitem?.controls?.batchSize?.invalid"
                            class="mkline-input" formControlName="batchSize">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 aligctr">
                        <button mat-stroked-button (click)="addNewType()" class="add-button default-button"
                            *ngIf="(items.controls.length-1) === i">
                            <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">
                                add_circle_outline
                            </mat-icon> Add New
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd have to check if there's an object with the same values in items. You could do that by writing your own function for comparison of objects (search SO for examples), use lodash (has a method that does just that, but I think it's an overkill to get lodash just for a method or two) or go silly: make a new array to hold concatenated strings of all the values in new items, so when you try to add new item check if concat of all its values already exists in that array. It's silly, but it makes the code and logic a bit shorter and more readable :)

Comment: @MishaMashina, Can you plz help me by adding some short code?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify to check if the objects are the same:

```
addNewType() {   
    // newRow -> new item (as object) to add
    // check if newRow values are already in items array:
    if (this.items.some(item =>
    JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(newRow) ) {
        console.log("error!"); // do your intended validation thing
    } 
    else {
         this.addItem(this.createItem(null));
    }       
}
```

However, I don't see how you get the values for the new item once you click the button? So `newRow` is just there as a placeholder.

Comment: this.items is a formgroup, So every new value has been added inside array only, this.items.value contain array of objects...

Comment: On every add new click, New object is added in below array..

Comment: this.items.value = [
    {productType: 'Laundry', processTechType: 'Continuous', subfamilyId: Array(1), lineId: Array(1), batchSize: 'NA'}
 {productType: 'Water Purification', processTechType: 'Batch', subfamilyId: Array(1), lineId: Array(1), batchSize: '34'}
];

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz example? I still don't see where you get the keys/values of the new item. I understand how it looks, but not where you get it.

Comment: Here i am getting the new object value.. this.makeLineForm.value
The new value is coming inside object like
{clusterId: 'Africa', clusterName: 'Africa', factoryName: 'Agbara - Laundry', factoryId: 'R_X001', makeLineName: '', …}